# Read input char by char

Tags: rust

I have the following function that read the user input `char` by `char`. By buffering the `char` in an array, I would like to have a string but fail so far with the error:

> expected 'char', found enum `termion::event::Key`

```
fn readtest() {
    let terminal = io::stdout().into_raw_mode();
    let mut stdout = terminal.unwrap();

    // Use asynchronous stdin
    let mut stdin = termion::async_stdin().keys();
    let mut s = String::new();

    loop {
        // Read input (if any)
        let input = stdin.next();

        // If a key was pressed
        if let Some(Ok(key)) = input {
            match key {
                // Exit if 'q' is pressed
                termion::event::Key::Char('q') => break,
                // Else print the pressed key
                _ => {
                    s.push(key);
                    stdout.lock().flush().unwrap();
                }
            }
        }
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(50));
    }
    s
}
```

Answer (score 2):

s is a `String` and key is a `Char(char)`. You cannot push directly key into s. You first need to use a matching pattern as follows:

```
 if let termion::event::Key::Char(k) = key {
       s.push(k);
 }
```